# Elixir Phoenix: Can I call a context function from a template, and should I

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to display a list of `article_categories` in an article form (used for creation and update) as a drop down input.

I have a function in my blog context (`blog.ex`) to retrieve all categories through Ecto and format the result as a drop-downable list:

```
defmodule MyApp.Blog do
  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias MyApp.Repo

  alias MyApp.Blog.ArticleCategory

  def get_categories() do
    MyApp.Repo.all from c in ArticleCategory, select: {c.title, c.id}
  end
end
```

In my template (`templates/article/form.html.heex`) I call my categories like this:

```
<%= select f, :category_id, MyApp.Blog.get_categories(), prompt: [key: "Choose your category"] %>
```

Visually I get the result I want, **BUT**... the literature seems to hint at passing  my categories as an assign.

Is there an issue in doing it this way? (performance? design?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm all for putting that logic in the controller. The main motivation here is *Separation of Concerns*:

- your controller is responsible for parsing incoming parameters and getting the correct data from the data/business layer
- your view layer is responsible for presenting that data to the user

One of the advantages is that you end up with a system that is easier to maintain and test.

I guess it can be hard to see why this would be a best practice, but as your application grows, it will show.

For example: a new requirement is that `get_categories` now only lists categories for which the user has access. With a controller assign you could create a controller test that contains something like `assert conn.assigns.categories == ["one", "two"]`. But when you fetch the categories in the view, the test would become something like `assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "<li>one</li><li>two</li>"` which is far more brittle (ie. it doesn't guarantee that there's no item 'three', or if you add a class to each `li` element then you have to update the test as well).

Comment: I get your point: in the case described above the context module is independent from `conn`. If the list is processed in the controller I can then match it with role base concerns (following your example). Thx.